# copy data from a QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I have some data in a QTableWidget, and I want the user to be able to copy them and past to Excel.

```
QTableWidget *_tableWidget = new QTableWidget();
_tableWidget->setRowCount(5);
_tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);

QStringList textHorizontal;
QStringList textVertical;

textHorizontal << "1" << "2" << "3" << "4" << "5";
_tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(textHorizontal);

QVector<double> colomns = {1,2,3,4,5};

for (int row = 0; row < 5; ++row)
{
    textVertical.append(QString::number(row));
    for(int i = 0; i < colomns.size(); i++)
    {
        QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem(QString::number(colomns[i]));

        item->setFont(QFont("Times", 10));

        if(row % 2 == 0)
        {
          item->setBackground(QBrush(Qt::lightGray));
        }
        _tableWidget->setItem(row, i, item);
    }
}

_tableWidget->setVerticalHeaderLabels(textVertical);
```

When I do this and try to copy some data, I see this error : 
"QAction::eventFilter: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+C"

Do you know why this occurs? Why is the shortcut ambigous and how can I fix this?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you another code ? Have you implemented something about the keyPressEvent ?

Comment: The code can't reproduce the error in Win 10 + Qt 10.1 mingw32.

Comment: Your code doesn't show enough to spot the error for eventFilter problems. Just a hint for copy/paste: subclass QTableWidget and implement your own event handler like this: void MyTableView::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{

  //if there is a control-C event copy data to the global clipboard
  if(event->key() == Qt::Key_C && event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
  {
    copyTriggered();//implement copy to clipboard here
    event->accept();
  }
  else
  {
    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
  }
}